# Review queues are misaligned in the new topbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, top-bar

The new topbar is live on Meta Stack Exchange, but it has a small problem: when opening the review queues, they are misaligned:

[image: screenshot of topbar review queue dropdown]

<sub>(tested on: Firefox 55 and Safari 10.1, macOS Sierra; Chrome on Windows 10)</sub>

Comment: whoops, fix is coming! thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @Paweł Off-topic to the original post. The Stack Exchange link in the left corner of the top bar is redirecting to MSE only, it is expected to stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Arulkumar it doesn't redirect to anywhere for me. Sure you mean left side of top bar and not the MSE logo below it? (Which always redirected to the homepage)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not anymore, it did for 6-8 minutes after go-live.

Comment: @Glorfindel huh, so probably another tiny bug.

Comment: It's already being discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301027/295232).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misalignment bug with the top bar's review queue dropdown has been fixed, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of top bar review queue dropdown]