# Opening top bar "StackExchange" link in new tab

Tags: bug, top-bar

The Stack Exchange logo on the left of the top bar allows middle-clicking/right clicking and clicking "open in new tab". This duplicates the page you're on. This can also be seen when hovering over it and looking at the URL preview: It's the same that's already open.

It should either do nothing and not act like a link (just like the icons on the right) or link to stackexchange.com.

Comment: It did nothing in the first iteration. Let's not bring that back: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301027/what-is-the-point-of-the-stack-exchange-logo-in-the-new-top-bar also relevant is this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301848/158100

Comment: No, it should still open its small menu and description on a normal click. But duplicating the current site definitely isn't intended. My browser already has a button for that.

Comment: It does seem that opening [se] would be more intuitive.