# Forward links different from the original stackoverflow community

Tags: feature-request, design, review, top-bar

I'm going to use the **Code Review** community as an example, but it works for several others as well:

When we are seeing a question on **stackoverflow** and we click on the icon on the top left side, we are redirected to the main page (https://stackoverflow.com/) of this community, perfect, as I believe it should be:

[image]

However, in **Code Review** for example as we have the habit of clicking on this icon from this position to return to the main page of the community, it actually indicates a visit to the **StackExchange**, making this work difficult:

[image]

My tip is that to keep the community standard, this top left icon change the logo to **Code Review** and when clicked takes you directly to the **Code Review** home page (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Luuklag no. All sites. It's part of a [bigger problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314426/ux-consistency-across-se-sites-with-the-new-layout-theme).

Comment: Well, SO is the odd one out then, so SO should change, not the rest

Comment: At a guess - and without trying it - I'd expect that SO, Super User, and Server Fault would exhibit the 'different' behavior. The common factor would be that they have their own domains rather than a subdomain of SE.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin no, the source of this confusion is Stack Overflow having its own unique design, very different from the rest of Stack Exchange sites. The specific issue the OP facing is due to Stack Overflow not having the "StackExchange" logo in the top left, as ***all other 170+ sites***, have.